# Replace text with regular expressions in a text editor

Tags: regex, text, notepad++, text-manipulation

I need to edit lines  in a text file.

The text files contains more than 100 lines of data in the below format.

```
 Cosmos Rh Us (Paperback)   $10.99   Shipped: 
 The Good Earth (Paperback) $6.66    Shipped: 
 BEST OF D.H. LAWRENCE (Paperback) $7.89 Shipped:
 ...
```

These are excerpts from the online book shop I use to buy books

I have this data in a test editor. How do I edit it [Fine/Replace] such that  the data becomes like this

```
  $10.99
  $6.66
  $7.89
```

or better, *without the dollar sign*, since it'll be easy total it.

I use notepad++ as text editor.

Answer (score 2):

Search for (don't forget to enable regular expressions in the replace box!)

```
^.*\$(\d+\.\d+).*$
```

and replace all with

```
\1
```

Comment: user said it would be better without the dollar sign

Comment: @garyh: Yes, the dollar sign will be removed as requested.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply match full lines and capture all numbers after the $ sign:

```
Find what: ^[^$]*\$(\d+\.\d+).*$
Replace with: $1
```

Make sure that you **don't** check the ". matches newline" option. And note that this will behave unexpectedly if you have multiple $ signs in a line.

You might need to update to Notepad++ 6. Before that some regex features were not working properly.

Answer (score 0):

Find:

```
((?<=\$)[\d\.]+)
```

Replace With:

`\1` or `$1` (whichever Notepad++ uses)

Comment: That is effectively a NOP because you write back what you have matched.

Comment: Ah, I'm with you now. I've just matched the actual text rather than the whole line to replace with the capture. Ignore me.

Comment: "no operation" what I was trying to say is, that your answer will leave any possible input unchanged.

Comment: Yep. Me trying to be clever :)

Answer (score 0):

first regex will be replaced with nothing

```
[a-zA-Z0-9].*\)
```

second regex will be replaced with nothing

```
[a-zA-Z]+\:
```